# Idle Scan with Windows 10 machine as a Zombie

Tags: network, windows, linux

I'm learning how to do an Idle scan and I'm practicing on my personal computers:

- I have a machine with port 21 open.
- I sent a SYN/ACK ping on the Windows 10 machine (the zombie) and I get `x` as the IP-ID
- then I sent a SYN ping to the target using the Windows 10 as a zombie.
- then I sent a SYN/ACK ping to the zombie once again, but instead of getting `x+2` as expected (since the 21 port is open) I got `x+1`.

I used hping3 and I dont know what I did wrong. The commands:

```
hping3 -SA <zombie> -c 1 
hping3 --spoof <zombie> -S <target> -p 21 -c 1
hping3 -SA <zombie> -c 1
```

Comment: It looks like you are pinging the zombie, getting x, pinging something else, then pinging the zombie again getting x+1. This would appear to be the expected behavior.

Comment: but isn't the zombie supposed to send a RST packet to the target with the ID x+1 with the command `hping3 --spoof <zombie> -S <target> -p 21 -c 1` or `hping3 -a <zombie> -S <target> -p 21 -c 1` ?